# zend framework custom validation classes

Tags: zend-framework

I'm writing a custom validator that is going to check for the existence of an email such that if it already exists in the database, the form is not valid. I'm having a hard time figuring out helper paths and namespaces for custom Zend_Validation classes.

I'd like to call the class My_Validate_EmailUnique but I keep getting error messages such as:
there is an error exception 'Zend_Loader_PluginLoader_Exception' with message 'Plugin by name 'My_Validate_EmailUnique' was not found in the registry; used paths: My_Validate_: /var/www/site/arc/helpers/

The class looks like this:

```
    <?php
class My_Validate_EmailUnique extends Zend_Validate_Abstract
{
    const EMAIL_UNIQUE = 'notMatch';
```

Can someone help me with where I register for the Zend_Form to look for custom validators?

Comment: Do you have a file EmailUnique.php in /var/www/site/arc/helpers/ and have you looked at the Db_NoRecordExists validator? I think it does what you need: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.validate.set.html#zend.validate.Db

Comment: Perhaps, I'm missing something on how Zend_Loader is actually doing this (or more likely Zend_Loader_PluginLoader. I have the file there and I have within the constructor of my form the following:

$email->addPrefixPath('My_Validate', APPLICATION_PATH .'/helpers/','validate');

Does Zend_Loader_PluginLoader use a different logic than Zend_Loader where the My_Validate_* would go to My/Validate.

It sounds like the Db_NoRecordExists might work but honestly, I want to figure out how this is working.

thanks David

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can directly add the validator to your form element. There is no need to write a custom validator for this.

In your form:

```
$element->addValidator(new Zend_Validate_Db_NoRecordExists('mytablename', 'myemailcolumnname'));
```

Comment: The fourth argument is useful if you want to define which `Zend_Db_Adapter` to use.

Answer (score 2):

+1 for [`Db_NoRecordExists`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.validate.set.html#zend.validate.Db) - the docs have an example showing exactly what you want to do.

Otherwise, custom validators can be loaded like regular library classes, so try placing it on your include path.

`/library/My/Validate/EmailUnique.php`

---

You can also add a new entry to the `Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader` if you want to keep it in your application folder, as opposed to your library:

```
// Bootstrap.php
protected function _initAutoloader()
{
    $autoloader = new Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader(array(
        'namespace' => 'My_',
        'basePath'  => dirname(__FILE__),
    ));

    $autoloader->addResourceType('validator', 'validators', 'Validate')

    return $autoloader;
}
```

And put the class `My_Validate_EmailUnique` in:

`/application/validators/EmailUnique.php`

I've never registered a custom validator as a plugin before, so I can't help you there sorry.

Comment: in terms of Db_NoRecordExists, how do you turn it off between an insert and an update. I use the same action (manageAction) and, on an update, I do not want it to be validated. It looks like I might be able to do a removeValidator but, ideally, I would like to be doing this not in the Controller but in the model (or possible a service). Any advice on if this is the right approach.